Custom credit taxonomy linked to user profile or no-email user profiles?
I'm trying to come up with a solution (plugin suggestions welcome) that allows authors to attach users/creators to a post.
For example: A Movie Blog with a post that is a movie review article.

In a custom repeater field, Author can give credit to "creator" such as a actor, director, producer etc, and input a name or select an existing user profile
Post displays the credits below the post body and links to either the taxonomy page or to the user profile if one exists.
If a user profile for the desired credit doesn't exist, Author can add it and include social media links and optionally an email to invite that person as a user.

I see 3 possible options
Option A: Create a creator or credit Taxonomy and Keep user profiles separate and just build out the taxonomy page to look like a profile page. Figure out taxonomy-user association later.
Option B: Create a custom field in the creator taxonomy to associate a user profile with the taxonomy value.
Option C: Forgo the creator taxonomy and build out user profiles to be able to be create by authors without emails and make them claimable.
Option B seems to me as the easiest to implement, but Option C seems the most logical data organization. But Option C has some hurdles with no-email profile creation and claiming or merging the profiles if and author credits @JohnnyDepp in a post and then Johnny creates a profile @JohnnyDepp1 and needs to claims or needs to merge his self created profile with the @JohnnyDepp profile the author created.
Appreciate any thoughts, insights or experience with creating a system like this.
